# Resize color palette when zoom level is changed in responsive mode in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am using Angular 15 and trying to resize the color palette based on zoom level.

```
<input #primaryColor (change)="colorChange($event,'primary')" formControlName="primaryColor" class="color-input" type="color">
```

The type is `color` for this.

When I change the view to Mobile Mode in Developer Tools and change the zoom level from 100% to 50% for example, the color palette is going out of the screen when I select zoom level from the Dropdown of the browser.

The screenshots for `Galaxy Fold` Mobile device is shown with `100%` and `75%` zoom levels. In `100%`, the color palette fits properly. But when the zoom level is changed to `75%`, the color palette is going out of scope.

[image: Color Palette 100%]

[image: Color Palette 75%]

How to resize and fit the color palette based on zoom level here?

Comment: Hi, am I understood your right, you need to change your palette (some colors) when zoom was changed, right?

Comment: When you are decreasing the zoom the colour palette window should also decrease to make it completely visible in the screen. For me now it is displaying outside of the given range

Comment: Removing of colours is not required

Answer (score 0):

The color selection is OS and browser based. So if its in android mobile the color selection will be done based on screen available and color picker will be different. So if you want to change the picker you can choose angular package available to use.

I hope this help.

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
```

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: If you are checking in desktop it will go out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to achieve this task.

The class is

```
   .color-palette {
      width: 50vw;
      height: 50vh;
    }
```

The media query is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-height: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-zoom: 1.5) {
  .color-palette {
    width: 75vw;
    height: 75vh;
  }
}
```

You can add more media queries for different sizes.

now just apply this class to the color input.

```
<div class="color-palette">
  <input #primaryColor (change)="colorChange($event,'primary')" formControlName="primaryColor" class="color-input" type="color">
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working. When I changed the percentage to 75%, it is going out of scope.